# mapDispatchToProps() in Connect() must return a plain object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

This is LoginScreenContainer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import LoginScreen from '../components/LoginScreen.js'
import * as AUTH_ACTIONS from '../actions/auth.js'

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loggedIn: state.AUTH.loggedIn
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    loginDefault: (username , password) => {
        dispatch(AUTH_ACTIONS.actions.loginDefault(username, password))
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

This is actions/auth.js

```
import types from '../utilities/types.js'

export const actions = {
    loginDefault: (username, password) => ({
        type: types.LOGIN_DEFAULT,
        meta: {
            type: 'api',
            path: '/users/token',
            method: 'POST'
        },
        payload: {username, password}
    })
};

export default actions
```

What is the best way to debug this. 
I cannot figure out which part goes wrong.
I have been thinking this for 3 days.
Guidance and help needed.
Thank you.

(I am fairly new to react)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dispatch lacks the return value, you should change it to

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ( { // <- forgot the wrapping with ( here
    loginDefault: (username , password) => {
        dispatch(AUTH_ACTIONS.actions.loginDefault(username, password))
    }
} ) // <- forgot closing of the wrapping with ) here
```

This is due to the nature of the arrow functions, and you seem to do it correctly for the state to props, so I believe it's a small oversight.

So, an arrow function that has this

```
const sample = argument => { return { test: '1' } }
```

equals to

```
const sample = argument => ( { test: '1' } );
```

But not to

```
const sample = argument => { test: '1' };
```

So if you use an arrow function, and you wish to return an object, you should either return it, or wrap it with `( )` brackets

Comment: @BrianRuchiadi actually the wrapping of the reply with ( { } )

Comment: Oh my god..
It was my lack of knowledge in ES6 that causes this error.
Thank you for pointing that out, man..

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I think that `mapDispatchToProps` is incorrect:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
  loginDefault: AUTH_ACTIONS.actions.loginDefault,
})
```

And then in your event handler:

```
this.props.loginDefault(username, password)
```

Comment: actually no, dispatch will be sent as an argument, he is just missing the wrapping of the result

Comment: Yeah, but why call `dispatch` inside `mapDispatchToProps`? For me it looks overengineering since you can do the same without `mapDispatchToProps` just by calling `this.props.dispatch(AUTH_ACTIONS.actions.loginDefault(username, password))` in any of his event handlers :)

Comment: Personally, my actions are only enums, that I can reuse inside reducers, but I mostly create my own mapDispatchToProps that simply calls the dispatch with the correct action type and arguments needed, I thought that's a pretty standard praxis

Comment: It's a matter o code styling I'd say. If that works for you then I'm totally fine with that.